# In network programming, there is a limit to number of sockets/connections, how webserver exceeds this limit?

Tags: sockets, network-programming, websocket

I have started exploring on the network programming in Linux using Socket. I am wondering how come webservers like Yahoo, google, and etc are able to establish million/billions of connections. I believe the core is only socket programming to access the remote server. If that is the case then how come billion and millions of people are able to connect to the server. It means billions/millions of socket connection. This is not possible right? The spec says maximum 5 socket connections only. What is the mystery behind it?

Can you also speak in terms of this - API?

```
listen(sock,5);
```

Comment: take a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350071/maximum-number-of-concurrent-connections-on-a-single-port-socket-of-server

Answer (score 0):

To get an idea of tuning an individual server you may want to start with [Apache Performance Tuning](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/misc/perf-tuning.html) and maybe [Linux Tuning Parameters](http://www.performancewiki.com/linux-tuning.html), though it is somewhat outdated. Also see [Upper limit of file descriptor in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970853/upper-limit-of-file-descriptor-in-linux)

When you got a number of finely tuned servers, a network balancer is used and it typically distributes IP traffic across a cluster of such hosts. Sometimes a DNS load balancing is used in addition to further split between IP balancers.

Here, if you are interested you can follow Google's Compute Engine Load Balancing, which provides a single IP address, and does away with the need to have DNS balancing in addition, and reproduce their results:

> The following instructions walk you step-by-step in setting up a
>   Google Compute Load Balancer benchmark that achieves 1,000,000
>   Requests Per Second. It is the code and step were used when writing a
>   blog post for the Google Cloud Platform blog. You can find the Google
>   Cloud Platform blog @ http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/ This
>   GIST is a combination of instructions and scripts from Eric Hankland
>   and Anthony F. Voellm. You are free to reuse the code snippets.
>   https://gist.github.com/voellm/1370e09f7f394e3be724

Comment: Does it mean that the same copy of server program is running on a various machines. Can I say these machines as the sub-servers or helper servers running the same piece of code.

Comment: It means that the network balancer has a large cluster of web servers behind it, and it splits the requests among them. Yes, typically these web servers will be completely identical.

Comment: It depends on the descriptor limit. In a Linux machine it may be 2048 fd. Now, one machine can support a maximum upto 2048 connections. So, it all depends on the number of clusters as well as on the load balancing algorithm. Am I thinking correctly?

Comment: No the limit on the number of fds is significantly higher. You will need to read about linux server tuning and increasing the maximum number of connections, say for Apache. There isn't a single source of information, so you may want to check serverfault and SO. But assuming you have highly tuned web servers, then you would put them behind a load balancer.

Comment: Thanks! By the way how many fd's we can have? Because fd will have only the meta data information. Is it equal to the number of inodes supported?

Comment: I updated the answer. I don't think you'll get all the info in one answer to one question, there is a long road ahead for you of research and tuning for your scenario :)

Comment: How about listen(sock,5);

Comment: cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max 
380594

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't 'say maximum 5 connections only'. The argument to listen() that you refer to is the backlog, not the total number of connections. It refers to the number of incoming connections that TCP will accept and hold on the 'backlog' queue() prior to the application getting hold of them via accept().

Comment: Does it mean that before calling accept, if any connections are missed, then  based on the backlog number it can still retrieve those connections?

Comment: It means that connections aren't 'missed' at all, they are accepted for you and put on the backlog queue, and that the backlog size has nothing to do with the maximum number of concurrent connections.